# Extract subset from the main query in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

In the below query, I get the count of customers who were active between "2017-09-01 00:00:00" and "2017-11-31 23:59:59" as cust_90 and would like to add another column to find the count of customers who were active between "2017-11-01 00:00:00" and "2017-11-31 23:59:59" (a subset of the whole period).

```
    select custid, count(distinct concat(visit1, visit2)) as cust_90
    from test1
    where date_time between "2017-09-01 00:00:00" and "2017-11-31 23:59:59"
    and custid = '234214124'
    group by custid;
```

Sample output:

```
    CustomerName    cust_90     cust_30
    David           38           15
```

Wondering whether I could have a subquery in the above query to find the customers active in a month. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: `2017-11-31 23:59:59` is an invalid datetime value.

Comment: @digital.aaron: That's how datetime is recorded in our system

Comment: November 31st? You might want to consult a calendar...

Comment: @digital.aaron: I get that - if that date is not present, then it would not find any data for that date.

Comment: What is your reason for using `count(distinct concat(visit1, visit2))` rather than `COUNT(DISTINCT custid)`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation which can be done using a `case` expression.

```
select custid, 
count(distinct concat(visit1, visit2) end) as cust_90,
count(distinct case when to_date(date_time)>='2017-11-01' then concat(visit1, visit2) end) as cust_30
from test1
where date_time >= '2017-09-01' and date_time < '2017-12-01'
and custid = '234214124'
group by custid;
```

Comment: You *still* don't need `TODATE()` now that you're using an exclusive end point ;)